# How do I fix F12 on IE 11.0.9600.17905 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I'm having problems with F12 loading on my computer, and several search engine searches all basically yielded the same information that's irrelevant to my scenario, so I thought I'd ask here. I'm running on a virtual desktop using a thin client that is configured with the following parameters:

> Intel Xeon CPU X5675 @ 3.07Ghz 3.06GHz
>
> Installed Memory: 4GB
>
> System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Internet Explorer information:

> Internet Explorer 11
>
> Version: 11.0.9600.17905
>
> Update Versions: 11.0.21 (KB3065822)
>
> ☑ Install new versions automatically

Whenever I try to use F12 (the debugger tools of Internet Explorer), I'm presented with the following information:

Diagnostic:
Exception in window.onload: Error
StackTrace:

```
Error at TraceWriter.prototype.raiseEventWithMessage (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:3230:21) at
TraceWriter.prototype.raiseEvent (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:3226:21) at
TraceWriter.prototype.raiseEventWithMessage (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/Common/CommonMerged.js:6674:17) at
TraceWriter.prototype.raiseEvent (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/Common/CommonMerged.js:6679:13) at DomExplorerWindow (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/dom/DomExplorerMerged:18391:17) at Anonymous function (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/dom/DomExplorerMerged.js:18306:25) at EventManager.prototype.dispatchEvent (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:3946:29) at checkAndFirePluginReady (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:4406:17) at setHostReady (res://C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:4418:13) at host.messageReceived (res://C:\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\F12Resources.dll/23/pluginhost/plugin.f12.js:4480:25)
```

Various searches have yielded obsolete results regarding a Windows 7 Security Update, which would already be on my system, as it is set to automatically update all software and use all available patches from Microsoft. The last update occurred today, but isn't related to this OS, which was installed about five weeks ago.

The window can be moved, resized, and closed, and the Help, Focus Internet Explorer, and dock/undock buttons work correctly, but I cannot change browser versions using the dropdown (no dropdown appears on clicking), and I cannot access the console, DOM tree, or any other tools that would normally appear.

Keep in mind this is a workstation, so I cannot just "refresh" my computer, but I do have administrative privileges, so I can generally enable/disable/repair any individual element and/or install/remove software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft F12 has open [BUG #1053496](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1053496/f12-developer-tools-dom-explorer-exception-in-window-onload-in-11-0-9600-17501-update-11-0-15) for it, since 12/12/2014.

> F12 Developer Tools DOM Explorer Exception in window.onload in 11.0.9600.17501 Update 11.0.15
>
> > Fresh install of IE11 on established Windows 7 32-bit PC with IE 9 on it results in an error on the F12 developer tools' DOM Explorer tab. Other tabs don't work. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/imposible-use-f12-developer-tools-exception-in/09b4f305-e436-4615-a8a5-705b0bc85bbd

I recently had similar [F12 error](https://twitter.com/laukstein/status/624121429731209218) on up-to-date Windows 7 machine, and no patch was able to fix it.
The only way I managed to fix it was to compliantly uninstall IE11 and after to upgrade IE trough Windows Update. Otherwise you need to wait till Microsoft'll fix #1053496 what might never happen.

Comment: The superuser moderator recently deleted my answer and ignores its update, so I the only way to answer was by opening this new answer.

Comment: Your post was converted to a comment, not deleted because it lacks content. See here for guidelines while posting an answer: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer If you've updated your answer, click on "Flag" & drop a message

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. Here is a solution if you don't mind editing system files:

1. Get http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
2. Open *C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\F12Resources.dll* in Resource Hacker
3. Go to resource HTML \ PLUGINHOST/PLUGIN.F12.JS,
4. Copy the content out in some editor
5. Add "//" in the beginning of line 3220 and line 3234 to disable the calls to "F12.Host.ExternalApis.traceWriter...."
6. Paste back to Resource Hacker, press F5 to compile
7. Save and replace the dll file, don't forget to backup before that.

I have no idea what happened to traceWriter, the workaround works anyway. This [chinese source](https://blog.csdn.net/u011138447/article/details/46918693) mentions problem with localState saved by website but clearing state and cache didn't work for me.